# No access to database

Tags: python, firebird

I am trying to open an FDB file, but it doesn't seem to work. Whatever I try, I get this error:

```
Opening ./20190401_database.fdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    conn = fdb.connect(dsn=local_copy, user='****', password='****', charset='iso8859_1')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fdb/fbcore.py", line 848, in connect
    "Error while connecting to database:")
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while connecting to database:\n- SQLCODE: -551\n- no permission for read-write access to database /var/www/wsgi/data/20190401_database.fdb', -551, 335544352)
```

I am running this code as user `apache`, and the same user just copied the FDB file into that location, so I am pretty sure the user has read/write access.

```
import fdb
from datetime import date, timedelta

DB_PATH="."

yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days = 1)
yesterday = yesterday.strftime("%Y%m%d")
filename = f'{yesterday}_database.fdb'
local_fullpath = f'{DB_PATH}/{filename}'

local_copy = local_fullpath

print("Opening "+local_copy)
conn = fdb.connect(dsn=local_copy, user='****', password='****', charset='iso8859_1')

conn.close()
```

Even when running the script as root, I get the same error.

Comment: please describe how did you install Firebird Server, which version, how did you check it is running, etc. Your question omits those points.

Comment: @Arioch'The I do not use the Firebird server, I use the `fdb` Python module to access a Firebird database file. There is only a process `fbguard` running ...

Comment: There is not "Python library to access Firebird database files".  FDB module is a library to access Firebird database [database management system, server, program, etc]. Quotes from FDB site: "FDB works with Firebird 2.0 and newer", "FDB is implemented on top of Firebird client library", etc

Comment: @Arioch'The OK (the way Firebird works differently from e.g. PostgreSQL or MySQL has confused me already a lot...). How can I find out the firebird version then?

Comment: @Arioch'The I am re-installing now, I have FB 2.5.8. And I already got the connection working (the FDB file had to be read/writeable by user `firebird`). Having issues with the charset now ...

Comment: Now, I do not knot what Firebird Server should look like on UNIX. On Windows FBGuard is long deprecated and a stand-alone server process should work on itself. But on UNIX firebird tend to "embedded server" module, be loaded as lib-so into a process. So, it may well be that FBGuard runs as a central process on UNIX loading engine lib-so. Or maybe it actls like xinetd and launches another Firebird server process on demand. I just don't know it. Anyway, you have to try connecting using isql or other Firebird native tools.

Comment: As of now it looks like Firebird Server process and user it runs from do not have access to the database file. Again, I don't know where it is situated on UNIX, but try to find `firebird.log` file and read into it.

Comment: With charset, you have to specify some charset for the very connection, most lazy way is to take UTF-8 for connection. Due to backward compatibility (overdone IMHO) Firebird still permits (even Java's Jaybird do) no-charset connection where all the texts are considered and transferred as binary raw dumps. You have to find how to provide charset (usually it is `lc_type` parame in connection string) for the connection creation command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191070/discussion-between-bart-friederichs-and-arioch-the).

Comment: I tried all kinds of charsets, none of them seem to work.

Comment: connection charset is truly important, but it is a separate issue worth a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the fact that the FDB file has to be read/writable by the `firebird` user.

Setting that correctly made it work.

Comment: I think it is crucially important to explain why is that. It is sadly common misconception that python itself somehow reads Firebird Databases, while it only passes reading requests to a discrete, stand-alone Firebird Database Server. The confusion with user rights stems from this misconception.

Comment: @Arioch'The FDB can also use embedded, but it looks like Bart has in fact installed Firebird server, which will route connections through the server using local IPC, and then Firebird server of course needs read/write access.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel but where is FB engine hosted on UNIX, in which process then? in FBGuard process? or would FBGuard on UNIX also spawn external FBSERVER/FB_INET_Server process to host engine libraries?